# Android - Google Analytics v4 hits generated but not sent

Tags: java, android, google-analytics, android-studio, google-analytics-firebase

I'm currently running into what seems to be a common issue though I think the reason I'm seeing it stems from something else.

```
02-18 12:00:13.854    3654-3672/com.mobileanalytics_test V/GAV4﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: connecting to Analytics service
02-18 12:00:13.867    3654-3672/com.mobileanalytics_test V/GAV4﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: connect: bindService returned true for Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.START cmp=com.google.android.gms/.analytics.service.AnalyticsService (has extras) }
02-18 12:00:13.872    3654-3672/com.mobileanalytics_test I/GAV4﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: No campaign data found.
02-18 12:00:13.872    3654-3672/com.mobileanalytics_test V/GAV4﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Initialized GA Thread
02-18 12:00:13.873    3654-3672/com.mobileanalytics_test V/GAV4﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Loaded clientId
02-18 12:00:13.874    3654-3672/com.mobileanalytics_test V/GAV4﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: putHit called
02-18 12:00:13.874    3654-3672/com.mobileanalytics_test V/GAV4﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Loaded clientId
02-18 12:00:13.874    3654-3672/com.mobileanalytics_test V/GAV4﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: putHit called
02-18 12:00:13.876    3654-3654/com.mobileanalytics_test V/GAV4﹕ Thread[main,5,main]: service connected, binder: android.os.BinderProxy@<Redacted>
02-18 12:00:13.877    3654-3654/com.mobileanalytics_test V/GAV4﹕ Thread[main,5,main]: bound to service
02-18 12:00:13.878    3654-3654/com.mobileanalytics_test V/GAV4﹕ Thread[main,5,main]: Connected to service
02-18 12:00:13.890    3654-3672/com.mobileanalytics_test V/GAV4﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Sending hit to service   PATH: <SNIP>
02-18 12:00:13.913    3654-3672/com.mobileanalytics_test V/GAV4﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Sending hit to service   PATH: <SNIP>
02-18 12:09:23.372    3654-3672/com.mobileanalytics_test V/GAV4﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Loaded clientId
02-18 12:09:23.372    3654-3672/com.mobileanalytics_test V/GAV4﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: putHit called
02-18 12:09:23.378    3654-3672/com.mobileanalytics_test V/GAV4﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Sending hit to service   PATH: <SNIP>
```

The part here that concerns me is that I don't ever see my dispatch fire despite it being configured to do so every 30 seconds in my global_tracker.xml file. Below is all relevant code, I've looked through it and every tutorial I could find and I cannot find what I'm doing wrong.

global_tracker.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:ignore="TypographyDashes">
    <string name="ga_logLevel">verbose</string>
    <int name="ga_dispatchPeriod">30</int>
    <bool name="ga_dryRun">false</bool>
    <string name="com.mobileanalytics_test.MainActivity">Test Activity Reporting</string>
</resources>
```

app_tracker.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:ignore="TypographyDashes">
    <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-XXXXXXXX-Y</string>
    <string name="ga_sampleFrequency">100.0</string>
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>
    <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>
    <integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">-1</integer>
    <screenName name="com.mobileanalytics_test.MainActivity">Test Activity Reporting</screenName>
</resources>
```

MyApplicationClass.java

```
public class MyApplicationClass extends Application {

    private static final String PROPERTY_ID = "UA-XXXXXXXX-Y";

    public enum TrackerName {
        APP_TRACKER,
        GLOBAL_TRACKER
    }

    HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker>();

    synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId) {
        if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {

            GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
            //Tracker t = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.app_tracker);
            Tracker t = (trackerId == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID)
            :  analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
            //Tracker t = (trackerId == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID)
            //        : (trackerId == TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker)
            //       : analytics.newTracker(R.xml.ecommerce_tracker);
            mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);

        }
        return mTrackers.get(trackerId);

    }
}
```

MainActivity.Java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Tracker tracker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //GoogleAnalytics googleAnalytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        //tracker.start("UA-XXXXXXXX-Y");

        //Get a Tracker (should auto-report)
        tracker = ((MyApplicationClass) getApplication()).getTracker(MyApplicationClass.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        //Get an Analytics tracker to report app starts and uncaught exceptions etc.
        tracker.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder("Test", "Load").build());
        //GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStart(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        //Stop the analytics tracking
        GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStop(this);
    }
}
```

I've been working at roughly this stage since yesterday so I'm in the process of testing the "just wait" solution. I am looking at the Real Time Overview and it's my understanding that my hits should show up there in close to real time, but I'm not seeing anything. I am targeting API 21 - Android 5.0.1

Any tips are welcome!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38380919/android-google-analytics-v4-sdk-not-tracking-realtime-on-july-2016  I am having same problem

Answer (score -2):

When running on Google Play Devices the Analytics SDK will try to connect to the Analytics Service provided by Google Play Services and send the hits for dispatching to the service. The service provides more reliable delivery mechanism as its not subject to the application process life time constraints. When using the Analytics Service local dispatching interval has no effect and the application hits are send over to the service without any delay. From your log it appears that you are successfully connecting to the service:

```
Thread[main,5,main]: service connected, binder: android.os.BinderProxy@...
```

and successfully sending the hits to be dispatched by the service:

```
Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Sending hit to service   PATH: <SNIP>
```

When Analytics service connection fails you will see a log message stating that and the hits will be dispatched from the app process according to the local dispatch interval. This will happen when your app is running on non-Google Play Devices (like Amazon Fire phone or emulator without Google Play Service) or Google Play Service is currently unavailable (the service is updating for example).

Comment: This really does not solve anything. Just copy + paste of the Analytics Service is.